# insert statement sql vb

Tags: sql, vb.net, combobox

i have a problem with insert statement when the comboboxitem is "ذكر" it's working ok, but when the combobox item is "انثي" it's not working and give this message

*String or binary data would be truncated.

*The statement has been terminated.

```
Dim char1 As String
Dim char2 As String = TextBox7.Text.Substring(0, 4)
Dim char3 As String = Label29.Text
'******************* تاريخ انتهاء صلاحية الشهادة الصحية'
If TextBox9.Text.Length = 10 Then
    HealthyIssue = TextBox9.Text
    HealthyExpire = HealthyIssue.AddDays(364)
    If ComboBox2.SelectedItem = "انثي" Then
        char1 = 2
        TextBox18.Text = char1 & char2 & char3
    ElseIf ComboBox2.SelectedItem = "ذكر" Then
        char1 = 1
        TextBox18.Text = char1 & char2 & char3
    End If

    Dim connString As String = "...................."
    Dim myConnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connString)
    myConnection.Open()
    Dim ss As String
    ss = "INSERT INTO PersonalData ([Name], [IDNo], [Gender], [PlaceOfWork],[birthPlace], [PassportNo], [Nationality], [SocialState], [Occupation], [Mobile], [VisaNo], [VisaIssueDate], [VisaExpireDate], [EntryDate], [HealthyIssueDate], [HealthyExpireDate], [ContractIssue], [Guarantor], [Guarantorplace], [GuarantorPhoneNo], [Note]) VALUES (@Name, @IDNo, @Gender,  @PlaceOfWork, @birthPlace, @PassportNo, @Nationality, @SocialState, @Occupation, @Mobile, @VisaNo, @VisaIssueDate, @VisaExpireDate, @EntryDate, @HealthyIssueDate, @HealthyExpireDate, @ContractIssue, @Guarantor, @Guarantorplace,  @GuarantorPhoneNo, @Note) "
    Dim cmdd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(ss, myConnection)
    cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", TextBox1.Text)
    cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDNo", TextBox18.Text)
    cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", ComboBox2.SelectedItem)
    cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PlaceOfWork", TextBox19.Text)
    cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@birthPlace", TextBox7.Text)
    cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PassportNo", TextBox6.Text)
    cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nationality", ComboBox3.Text)
    cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SocialState", TextBox8.Text)
    cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Occupation", ComboBox4.Text)
    cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", TextBox5.Text)
    cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VisaNo", TextBox14.Text)
    cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VisaIssueDate", TextBox15.Text)
    cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VisaExpireDate", TextBox16.Text)
    cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EntryDate", TextBox17.Text)
    cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HealthyIssueDate", TextBox9.Text)
    cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HealthyExpireDate", HealthyExpire)
    cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContractIssue", TextBox10.Text)
    cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Guarantor", TextBox11.Text)
    cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Guarantorplace", TextBox12.Text)
    cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GuarantorPhoneNo", TextBox13.Text)
    cmdd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Note", TextBox19.Text)
    cmdd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    cmdd.Dispose()
```

Comment: Can you clarify where in your code the error happens?

Answer (score 1):

For errors related to a SQL table, it's generally a good idea to provide the table definition (or relevant parts of it) in your question.  Based on what you have in the question now...

The one that works seems to be 3 characters, and the one that does not seems to be 4 characters.

Possibly your column is defined as NVARCHAR(3) or NCHAR(3).

If it is defined as wider, your database column type is probably CHAR or VARCHAR, rather than NCHAR or NVARCHAR.

The number of bytes in the Unicode representation of "ذكر" is short enough to fit in the designated amount of storage, but the number of bytes in "انثي" is not.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is column length is not equal to the string coming from `combobox` item.

Two way to correct is modify the table structure to adjust the length of column for that input, or validate the user input to only 3 characters.

A little advise, it is best practice to use a `STORED PROCEDURE`, because an inline SQL Statement is vulnerable to SQL Injection attack. Specially when you are passing a `STRING` on your Query.

Also if want to avoid unexpected result or error, just minimize using `.Parameters.AddWithValue` because in that kind of process the datatype parameters in not well define , you can replace it using `.Parameters.Add` then you can define the datatype.

something like:

```
    .Parameters.Add("@ParameterName", DataType, Lenght).Value = ValueHere

    .Parameters.Add("@IDNo", SqlDbType.Int, 5).Value = TextBox18.Text
```

We can always avoid unexpected result and errors if use the best practices in coding.